# Получение списка занятых файлов

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Задача состоит в следующем:

> получить с сервера список файлов, занятых другими пользователями.

Пробовал через NetFileEnum, но с ним были проблемы (некоторые пути по каким-то причинам написаны капсом и не все файлы отображались в списке).

Есть ли какие-нибудь альтернативные способы, или хотя бы решение этих проблем с NetFileEnum?

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос. Настолько, насколько это возможно.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к предыдущему комментатору и, кроме этого, очень сильно призываю переформулировать вопрос, ибо, что такое "список занятых файлов" и о каком сервере речь, честно говоря, неясно даже сейчас.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что Вам надо получить список файлов, хранящихся на некой машине в сети, которые в текущее время кем-то открыты?